# Is there a generic InkCanvas StrokesChanged type of event?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, inkcanvas

Essentially what I'm trying to do is trigger a sort of 'dirty' state for my canvas, so that I know if there are unsaved changes.

**Is there an event in the WPF InkCanvas that I can use to handle any time when the strokes change?**

**If there isn't, what events should I listen to for the equivalent?** My first guess would be these:

```
StrokeCollected
StrokeErased
StrokesReplaced
```

Though I could be wrong, and be missing an edge case.

Note: It's not a big deal if I get false positives (marked dirty when it is in fact not), but I don't want false negatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like these events will do the job:

- `InkCanvas.StrokesReplaced` (occurs when the Strokes property is set)
- `StrokeCollection.StrokesChanged` (occurs when a stroke is added or removed)
- `Stroke.StylusPointsChanged` (occurs when the shape of a stroke is changed)
- `Stroke.StylusPointsReplaced` (occurs when the StylusPoints property is set)
- `Stroke.DrawingAttributesChanged` (occurs when the attributes of a stroke are changed)
- `Stroke.DrawingAttributesReplaced` (occurs when the DrawingAttributes property is set)

In my case, I never replace properties, or change drawing attributes, so I only use `StrokeCollection.StrokesChanged` and `Stroke.StylusPointsChanged`. Here is a snippet of my code.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    inkCanvas.Strokes.StrokesChanged += Strokes_StrokesChanged;
}

private void Strokes_StrokesChanged(object sender, StrokeCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Mark dirty
    foreach (Stroke stroke in e.Added)
    {
        stroke.StylusPointsChanged += stroke_StylusPointsChanged;
    }
    foreach (Stroke stroke in e.Removed)
    {
        stroke.StylusPointsChanged -= stroke_StylusPointsChanged;
    }
}

private void stroke_StylusPointsChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Mark dirty
}
```